# MVC5 OWIN ADFS Authentication loop issue - Thinktecture ResourceAuthorizationManager

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, owin, thinktecture-ident-model

I have a peculiar problem with an MVC5 web app. It uses a pretty standard implementation of OWIN an the Thinktecture ResourceAuthorizationManager.

It is configured to work with ADFS.

The problem that I am facing is that after the app has been deployed and has been running on the server (IIS in server 2012R2) for some time, when you try to login you get stuck in an authentication loop. I have added a trace and it shows that IsAuthenticated is false, even after successful postback from ADFS.

If I recycle the app pool it all starts working as expected for a short while.

I am in great need of some pointers of where to look.

Edit:
Found the solution elsewhere. Answer can be found here: [Intermittent redirection loops during ADFS authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559237/intermittent-redirection-loops-during-adfs-authentication/28580067#28580067)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Intermittent redirection loops during ADFS authentication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559237/intermittent-redirection-loops-during-adfs-authentication)

Answer (score 2):

In your global.asax.cs add an empty Session_Start event.

```
protected void Session_Start()
{
//Needed for Thinktecture to write AspCoookie
//https://github.com/IdentityServer/Thinktecture.IdentityServer3/issues/1003
}
```

Comment: Can you please expand a bit on why this is needed / what does it do?