# WsFederation Authentication login loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, owin, ws-federation

I am experiencing a problem with a login loop when using `WsFederation Authentication` in my MVC web application. I used visual studio to create the scaffolding of the web application and to setup the `WsFederation` in the `Startup.cs`. Which generates the following block of code:

```
public class Startup
{
    private static string realm = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:Wtrealm"];
    private static string adfsMetadata = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ida:ADFSMetadata"];

    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());

        app.UseWsFederationAuthentication(new WsFederationAuthenticationOptions
        {
            Wtrealm = realm,
            MetadataAddress = adfsMetadata
        });
    }
}
```

The web application is hosted in Azure and the ADFS is on premises.

On some clients, when a login attempt is made the login page goes into a loop requesting a new tokens causing the following exception on the ADFS Server:

> Exception details: 
>   Microsoft.IdentityServer.Web.InvalidRequestException: MSIS7042: The same client browser session has made '6' requests in the last '7' seconds. Contact your administrator for details.

I have read many articles on StackOverflow and looked at the various examples provided by the guys who wrote IdentityServer and I have tried the various configuration options and I cannot isolate the problem to a specific area.

From what I read it is a general problem with the OWIN middle ware loosing context of the object and as a result the token gets "lost".

I have attempted to implement some of the [sample code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28559237/intermittent-redirection-loops-during-adfs-authentication) that other have provided on StackOverflow but, I cannot seem to find a solution the resolves my problem or maybe a have not implemented the code correctly.

Any Ideas?

Comment: I have been able to replicate the problem on my local environment, but I am not closer to fully understanding the cause of the problem. I have added a my IP as a binding to my IIS Express configuration so that I can access the website remotely to debug. Doing so has made it possible to replicate the loop consistently. When I access the site from the "192.168.1.20:44341/"; the login works. However, when I access the site from "localhost:44341/"; the login loop occurs. The Relying Party Trust Endpoint IP address is my IP address.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cause of the problem was the request and response URLs where not the same. I.e. When a user entered the website URL and did not prefix it with HTTPS the redirect loop would occur.

The cause was hidden because the user is immediately redirected to ADFS if they are not authenticated or authorized.

All I had to do was to ensure that all user requests are redirected back to the HTTPS URL and that the HTTP binding is removed.(Either or would have worked just fine)

This is the code I used to ensure that all requests are redirect to https.

```
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to https">
          <match url="(.*)"/>
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="Off"/>
            <add input="{REQUEST_METHOD}" pattern="^get$|^head$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}"/>
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
```

I hope this post was helpful.