# .NET 4.0 WSFed application keep redirecting to ADFS only in IE after successful authentication

Tags: single-sign-on, adfs, ws-federation, adfs4.0

After enabling SSO with ADFS my application is working fine with Chrome and Firefox. But with IE its getting [6 times redirection issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37883783/wsfederation-authentication-login-loop). This is working fine with IE in IIS Express.

I have checked with Fiddler and found in IE after setting FedAuth cookie its getting lose. Then its redirecting again to the ADFS.

[image: Fiddler Trace]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was due to underscore (_) character in my domain name. IE wont allow domain names with _ and refuse to create the cookie.
[Refer to this.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11610106/2179430)

Note: Redirection between ADFS and Application happens due to various reasons. In my case it was working fine on other browsers.

Comment: I am hitting the same issue but for me i dont have Underscore in App URL then how huh?

Comment: @Nawaf, is your application getting this issue only on IE or not?